# What is ARGF.class in Ruby 1.9?

Tags: ruby, class, ruby-1.9

In Ruby 1.8.7, [the documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/) does not list `ARGF` under classes and modules, and `ARGF` isn't a class or a module:

```
ARGF.class # => Object
```

In Ruby 1.9.3, [the documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/) has `ARGF` under classes and modules, but I see this:

```
ARGF.class # => ARGF.class
ARGF.superclass # => NoMethodError: undefined method `superclass' for ARGF:ARGF.class
ARGF.class.superclass # => Object
```

- Why does Ruby 1.9 documentation place `ARGF` as a class when the actual class is something else?  Or are they the same thing?
- Is `ARGF.class` a metaclass, a virtual class, singleton class, or something else?

Comment: Check out https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/ruby-talk-google/ADQI5rhuJms. They toss out a few ideas to this question.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`ARGF` is implemented in C and you can do weird things in it. The `ARGF` class is defined there first. It is not set to any constant in Ruby, but its name is set to "ARGF.class".
Then `ARGF` constant is set to an instance of that class.

```
rb_cARGF = rb_class_new(rb_cObject);
rb_set_class_path(rb_cARGF, rb_cObject, "ARGF.class");
/* ... */
argf = rb_class_new_instance(0, 0, rb_cARGF);
rb_define_global_const("ARGF", argf);
```

Here is a Ruby code that is doing roughly the same thing.

```
argf_class = Class.new
def argf_class.name
  "ARGF.class"
end
argf = argf_class.new
ARGF = argf
```

It does not look reasonable in Ruby, but in C it is fine. Although, I think the class could be set to `ARGFClass` like `NilClass`, `TrueClass`, `FalseClass`, so that it is not confusing.

I don't know the history of the change. I think Ruby core folks wanted to get `ARGF` into the docs and this was the simplest way. (RDoc can't show documentation for singleton objects.)

Comment: +1 for finding and showing the C implementation.  I still wonder though about what actually changed between 1.8 and 1.9.  The 1.8 approach made sense; I have no idea what is going on now in 1.9.  I can't imagine that the Ruby folks would have purposely introduced something that was confusing, but somehow I haven't been able to find a clean description of the semantics.

Comment: I agree that it should be given the name `ARGFClass`.

Comment: @Seymon Accepted, though there's still one change of interest.  Ruby 1.8.7 shows `ARGF.class` to be `Object` but now it is something different.  I guess a comparison of the C implementations is warranted here.  Good hypothesis on having the doc writers trying to bring in descriptions of objects of singleton classes, though.

Comment: ARGF.class is not Object because it is now an instance of a special class. It's name is explicitly set to "ARGF.class" on the second line. I guess it would be something like #<Class:0x007ffc55120d50> otherwise.

Answer (score 7):

It seems correct that `ARGF` is not a class or a module.

```
class ARGF
end
# => TypeError: ARGF is not a class

module ARGF
end
# => TypeError: ARGF is not a module
```

The documentation lists `ARGF` under class, but other than that, it does not say it is a class. Probably, it was not intended that `ARGF` handled as a class, and it is wrong of the documentation to have listed as such. It is the documentation's bug.

It looks like `ARGF` if the only instance of a certain class, which lacks a literal, and the only way to refer to it is to call `ARGF.class`.

```
ARGF.class.class
# => Class

ARGF.class.ancestors
# => [ARGF.class, Enumerable, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

The usual relation between class and its instance holds for `ARGF.class` and `ARGF`.

```
ARGF.is_a?(ARGF.class)
# => true

ARGF.kind_of?(ARGF.class)
# => true
```

Answer (score 4):

If we capture the objects and look at them using just pure Ruby we can see a few things:

```
1.9.3 (Object#main):0 > ARGFClass = ARGF.class                                                                                                                                      
=> ARGF.class
1.9.3 (Object#main):0 > ARGFClass.name                                                                                                                                              
=> "ARGF.class"
1.9.3 (Object#main):0 > ARGFClass.class                                                                                                                                             
=> Class
1.9.3 (Object#main):0 > ARGFClass.superclass                                                                                                                                        
=> Object
1.9.3 (Object#main):0 > ARGFClass.ancestors                                                                                                                                         
=> [ARGF.class,
    Enumerable,
    Object,
    JSON::Ext::Generator::GeneratorMethods::Object,
    PP::ObjectMixin,
    Kernel,
    BasicObject]
```

For some reason, the developers have explicitly set the class.name value to return `ARGF.class`, which is generally uncommon but is used internally in Ruby for constants that should never be accessed directly.

We can instantiate objects with the ARGFClass exactly the same as any other class. That means it is a real Ruby class:

```
1.9.3 (Object#main):0 > argfinstance = ARGFClass.new                                                                                                                                
=> ARGF
1.9.3 (Object#main):0 > argfinstance.inspect                                                                                                                                        
=> "ARGF"
```

It's not just returning the singleton when you call #new either:

```
1.9.3 (Object#main):0 > argfinstance == ARGF                                                                                                                                        
=> false
1.9.3 (Object#main):0 > argfinstance.object_id                                                                                                                                      
=> 70346556507420
1.9.3 (Object#main):0 > ARGF.object_id                                                                                                                                              
=> 70346552343460
```

The Ruby developers have intentionally named the `ARGF.class` in such a way that it can't be referenced directly by name, but it is a real class and `ARGF` is a real object.

It has a lot of the same methods as an IO object, and in fact is defined in the `io.c` source file. It also has the Enumerable module mixed in so it supports all the each/inject/map functionality.

edit: The documentation lists `ARGF` as a class. However, its actually a constant referencing a singleton instance of the oddly named `ARGF.class` class.

### References

- https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/ruby-talk-google/argf.class/ruby-talk-google/ADQI5rhuJms/1M8I4_MpjuwJ
- http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/ARGF

Answer (score 0):

ARGF is an Array class.
see some examples at https://github.com/DouglasAllen/Ruby_core_ri_doc/tree/master/ARGF
Maybe not by name but you will be able to tell by using it like any array except that you may pass command line arguments into it. Try to add something else just to see what happens.